# How to add custom image/ design on the cupcake wrapper?

Tags: uv, image, texture-painting

I have modelled a cupcake on which I would like to add different styles of wrappers. I tried texture painting on them. But the result was not satisfactory. How do I use custom images on my wrapper or texture paint the polka pattern?

This is the modelled cupcake on which I would like to have the below looks:
[image: CupcakeModel]

[image: This is the cupcakeModel]

The polka dot (Tried texture painting in blender)
[image: polka Pattern]

Or use a custom image like this one
[image: The custom Image]

I would appreciate any help/ links to follow. Thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is what a *Cylinder Projection* unwrap gives, so you can easily paint on an image in the *Image Editor* or project a custom image:

[image]

If you want to paint in the 3D view, create a cylinder (that has a bit larger radius as folds tend to shrink the radius of the object) and paint on it, then use the result on your object.